# HikariCP Connection Leaks but connections are closed

Tags: java, mysql, sql, connection, hikaricp

Good day, following thing, I have closed MySQL connection everywhere but I still have connection leaks. After few weeks of researching I've found a solution for it.

Problem:

```
Connection method:
// Gets the MySQL connection.
public Connection getMySQLConnection () throws SQLException
{
    // Checks if the data source is not null!
    if (this.hikariDataSource != null)
    {
        // Returns the connection.
        return this.hikariDataSource.getConnection();
    }
    else
    {
        // Debugs that the data source is null.
        StringUtils.sendInformation("HikariDataSource is null!");

        // Returns null.
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the problem in the code posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution of my problem. You need to close the HikariDataSource too and if the connection is needed you need to open it again.

```
Method:
// Gets the MySQL connection.
public Connection getMySQLConnection () throws SQLException
{
    // Checks if the data source is not null!
    if (this.hikariDataSource != null)
    {
        if (this.hikariDataSource.isClosed())
            this.setHikariConfig();

        // Returns the connection.
        return this.hikariDataSource.getConnection();
    }
    else
    {
        this.setHikariConfig();

        if (this.hikariDataSource != null)
            return this.hikariDataSource.getConnection();

        StringUtils.sendServerInformation("Datasource is null!", "HikariCP");

        // Returns null.
        return null;
    }
}

public void closeMySQLConnection () throws SQLException
{
    if (this.hikariDataSource != null)
    {
        if (!(this.getMySQLConnection().isClosed()))
            this.getMySQLConnection().close();

        if (!(this.hikariDataSource.isClosed()))
            this.hikariDataSource.close();
    }
}
```